# If null get current date

Tags: php, mysql

in PHP page suppose I have 
select * from table where date=$curdate 
How can I the data according to user date? 
each user has its own timezone of course

Thanks

Comment: would be nice to know what language, system, database or whatsoever you are asking about...

Comment: You should tag the language you are using for more exposure and so readers know what language you are working with

Comment: php, mysql,I'm sorry guys

Comment: it's better to check if !empty($_GET['curdate']) in case you get empty parameter which is not null of course

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this

```
  <?php

 date_default_timezone_set('Africa/Cairo');//your time zone
 if(array_key_exists('curdate', $_GET) )
 { 
$curdate=$_GET['curdate'];
 }
 else
 {
$curdate=date('Y-m-d');
 }

 ?>
```

Also if your PHP.ini is configured correctly your default timezone will be what you configured it to be.

Comment: it works fine, but I went to another problem!
the whole process works like that:
the variable " curdate" is passed from another page to the current page and then the process works fine
but if the user got the direct link to the current page he will got error message " undefined variable
how can I avoide that please

Comment: @armia Is your website online?

Comment: I have updated the answer. Please Check.

Comment: @Me123 yes
home page http://abounamourad.net/ >>>> the link is "الصلاة الكتابية"
the url of the mentioned page is http://abounamourad.net/view-reading.php

Comment: @souvickcse 
same problem

Comment: isset should work but still you can try array_key_exists('curdate', $_GET) also. And please comment the full error description.

Comment: @ souvickcse
Notice: Undefined variable: curdate in

Comment: @ souvickcse Dear the problem is if the user went directly to the current page , the variable " curdate" will not exist because it should delivered from the home page, I hope this clarify!
thanks very much, 
I think we need to check if it is not set

Comment: Please check the answer, i think it will solve your problem now. One upvote will be usefull for me :)